# Is this the best platform for general use?

Tags: go-ethereum

I joined in because I saw a moral position I valued at ethereum.org. My initial post was poorly expressed - my apologies for that. I have tried for 2 months to set up for mining and continually get responses from geth stating there are various problems preventing me from synching. I updated to geth 1.8.1 and after 48 hours get the same reports. My PC (AMD A12-9800 RADEON R7 4 CPU cores, 8 GPU cores, 8Gb RAM) has been online all of this time, and been processing. I would like to create my own crypto-currency without regard to its value in the real world, but I need to know the platform for doing so is both credible and works. The command I entered (after stopping a run using geth 1.7 and installing 1.8.1) is 
geth --cache=6144 --syncmode "fast" --datadir     `"D:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum" --etherbase "0xc..."
and the most recent output is:
INFO [02-25|10:01:50] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=0s        processed=22196723 pending=19162 retry=0   duplicate=8656 unexpected=47101
INFO [02-25|10:02:02] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=16.067ms  number=5153154 hash=ef8ede…972dc1 ignored=0
INFO [02-25|10:02:09] Imported new state entries               count=1152 elapsed=12.019ms  processed=22197875 pending=18982 retry=0   duplicate=8656 unexpected=47101
INFO [02-25|10:02:15] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=5.008ms   number=5153155 hash=d043a1…a93f3a ignored=0
INFO [02-25|10:02:29] Imported new state entries               count=1152 elapsed=11.017ms  processed=22199027 pending=18883 retry=0   duplicate=8656 unexpected=47101
WARN [02-25|10:02:42] Rolled back headers                      count=321  header=5153155->5152834 fast=5153083->5152834 block=0->0
WARN [02-25|10:02:42] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a979fb575495b8d6 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
INFO [02-25|10:11:27] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [02-25|11:11:27] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0`

Thanks Mike

Comment: Hi there. What are the errors reporting while you're syncing? What are the options you're using to start Geth? What are you seeing with Geth 1.8.1? What are you're hardware specs? What platform? What "reports"? (By including that link it sounds a little like you're pushing an agenda... )

Comment: Reworded although I see now I need to read other guidelines about asking questions

Comment: @MikeMcEwan It seems you are syncing to the D: drive is it a HDD? Is it connected through usb port? If you are serious about mining you should use a SSD connected through pci. Before geth v1.8 it was impossible to sync with HDD (after two weeks I give up), switched to a SSD an synced in one day. Since two days I'm trying to sync with a HDD WD 1TB disk, it is close 5.1M blocks synced but not there yet. Also I'm unsure it will be able to keep up with the current rithm of mainnet.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael. It is an internal HDD with PC set up with C: as the Windows drive and D: as the user data drive. I'll sort out getting an internal SSD and try again. If there is any guidance on minimum H/W spec to support a user-created currency I'd appreciate a link. I'm aiming to use Ethereum as the basis for a currency to be used inside a relatively small group but want them to be able to use fairly standard home PC kit.

Comment: @MikeMcEwan I'm not a miner so can't give proper  hardware for that task, perhaps a better place to ask about mining hardware setups is reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking this question in the wrong place. There can't be a single authority that is trying to "con" you, read more about Ethereum here http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ and you should have a bit more direction and understanding. As mentioned above the link probably shouldn't have been posted as this place is more for questions directly relating to Ethereum.

Comment: Reworded with my apologies - I was a bit tired and frustrated, and I also need to read the guidelines and check at the link you supplied